# Do people with centralist political views have a higher IQ then those with extreme political views?

Tags: united-states, politics, intelligence

This [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/unique-everybody-else/201305/intelligence-and-politics-have-complex-relationship) claims that those with centralist political affiliation have a higher IQ then those with more extreme political views.

I've already inspected the original study linked, it is informative but limited.  I'm wondering if this trend has/can be confirmed in any other studies or with larger data sets?  I'd also be interested specifically rather this trend is seen within the US or if data sets within the US also demonstrate this trend.

Comment: I don't think this article is making that claim. It gives a review of the competing hypotheses, and some evidence for and against. It argues that more research is required because the links aren't clear. So, it appears to answer your question. Perhaps I have misunderstood your question? Are you able to clarify?

Comment: I can at least argue its wise to listen to the two sides of a history. That automaticaly excludes extremists =)